# Using Regex Subpatterns in Object Keys (using .replace())

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a question about the way .replace() works

I know that we can use subpatterns within the replace text like this

```
var somestr="foobar";
var newstr = somestr.replace(/foo([a-zA-Z]*)/g,"bar$1")
alert(newstr) //"barbar"
```

However, I am wondering if it is even possible to use the subpattern in an object property, like this.

```
var somestr = "foobar";
var someobj = {bar:'fuu',two:'uuf'}

var newstr = somestr.replace(/foo([a-zA-Z]*)/g, someobj["$1"])

alert(newstr) //"fuu" ?
```

My expected result would have been to get the `'bar'` property of `someobj`, which would be `"fuu"`, however the actual result is `undefined`, which would lead me to believe this is impossible.

How could I otherwise accomplish similar functionality?
Perhaps one of you JS gurus could shed some light on this.

The real-world purpose behind this is I have a template system that uses shorttags to display pieces of data from a requested JSON object, who's code I am attempting to streamline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not like this, I added $1 to show the fail:

```
var somestr = "foobar";
var someobj = {bar:'fuu',two:'uuf', $1: 'test'}

var newstr = somestr.replace(/foo([a-zA-Z]*)/g, someobj["$1"])

newstr; // "test";
```

but this would work:

```
var somestr = "foobar";
var someobj = {bar:'fuu',two:'uuf', $1: 'test'}

var newstr = somestr.replace(/foo([a-zA-Z]*)/g, "$1")

someobj[newstr]; // fuu
```

or maybe better yet, replace takes a function:

```
var somestr = "foobar";
var someobj = {bar:'fuu',two:'uuf', $1: 'test'}

var newstr = somestr.replace(/foo([a-zA-Z]*)/g, function () {
    return someobj[arguments[1]];
})

newstr; // fuu
```

Comment: Wow, mad ups on your second example, didn't know the function took the subpatterns as parameters. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: why doesn't it accept arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var someString = "foobar";
var someObject= {bar:'fuu',two:'uuf'};
var re = /foo([a-zA-Z]*)/g;

if (re.test(someString)) {
    alert(someObject[RegExp.$1]);
}
```

See the fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/nickyt/AjjjP

You could also just do this `alert(someObject[someString.replace(/foo([a-zA-Z]*)/g, "$1")]);` but the problem with this is, if nothing is found in $1, your object looks for am empty string key. I would stick with what I have above.